# How to count rows in one table based on another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have two tables in a MySQL database. The first one has a list of department names.

```
departments
    abbreviation | name
    -------------|-------------
    ACC          | accounting
    BUS          | business
    ...
```

The second table has a list of courses with names that contain the department's abbreviation.

```
courses
    section      | name
    -------------|-------------
    ACC-101-01   | Intro to Accounting
    ACC-110-01   | More accounting
    BUS-200-02   | Business etc.
    ...
```

I'd like to write a query that will, for each row in the `departments` table, give me a count of how many rows in the `courses` table are like the abbreviation I have. Something such as this:

```
    abbreviation | num
    -------------|--------------
    ACC          | 2
    BUS          | 1
    ...
```

I can do this for one individual department with the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE section LIKE '%ACC%'
    (gives me 2)
```

Although I could loop through in PHP and do the above query many times, I'd rather do it in a single query. This is the pseudocode I'm thinking of...

```
SELECT department.abbreviation, num FROM
    for each row in departments
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM classes WHERE section LIKE CONCAT('%',departments.abbreviation,'%)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT d.abbreviation, COUNT(*) num
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.section LIKE CONCAT(d.abbreviation, "%")
GROUP BY d.abbreviation
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9e2c/6)**

Comment: It works! And in a lot less code than I was expecting. And in a lot less time than I expected too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I quick solution, but not the best, could be:

```
SELECT abbreviation, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses C WHERE D.abbreviation = SUBSTRING(C.abbreviation, 0, 3)) AS c 
FROM departments D;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
select
    d.abbreviation,
    count(d.abbreviation) count
from
    departments d
inner join
    courses c
on (LOCATE(d.abbreviation,c.section) <> 0)
group by d.abbreviation;
```

Comment: Actually I prefer Steve's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT d.abbreviation, COUNT(*) num
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.section LIKE CONCAT(d.abbreviation, "%")
GROUP BY d.abbreviation
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems like you're asking a follow-up question here, rather than giving a new answer. If that's the case, you should ask a whole new question, not post it as an answer here.