# How to count rows in one table based on another table in mysql 2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219140/how-to-count-rows-in-one-table-based-on-another-table-in-mysql) but I have a problem.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cfd9/2) (I changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`)

What if there is a row in my `departments` (DDD for example) and **no association** in the `courses` table .

As you can see in the fiddle the count for DDD department is 1 like the BUS department has even if there is no data for DDD department. I know that `LEFT JOIN` does this but how can I modify this ?

**How do I get count = 0 for the DDD department?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `COUNT(c.section)` so when section results null for no association then in count it evaluates to zero

```
SELECT d.abbreviation
, COUNT(c.section) num
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN courses c ON c.section LIKE CONCAT(d.abbreviation, "%")
GROUP BY d.abbreviation
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cfd9/7)