# Database Query Issue with count of each row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have Two tables with following structure

```
details
---------------
id | session_id
1    1
2    1
3    1

details_extra
---------------
id | details_id
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
```

Output I am looking for is -

```
output
---------------
id  | subscribers(count)
1     2
2     1
3     1
```

The query I am writing is -

```
select id, count(details_extra.id) from details left join details_extra on
details_id = details.id where session_id='1';
```

output I get is

```
{id:1, subscribers:4}
```

Can any one please help.

Edit - 
Got it working by adding a Group By.

Comment: you didn't provide a `group by`...

Comment: Thanks. Got it working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count rows in one table based on another table in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219140/how-to-count-rows-in-one-table-based-on-another-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by id:

```
select id, count(details_extra.id) from details left join details_extra on
details_id = details.id where session_id='1' group by id;
```